# Kubernetes stateful set are not using storage class to create persistance volume

Tags: java, docker, redis, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to kubenetes. I have setup a cluster of kubernetes on two machine. and when I am deploying pods using stateful set.But kubernetes is not creating pvc.

I am doing POC for installing redis cluster on kubernets cluster, So For that I have downloaded a stateful set from below site url.
[https://medium.com/zero-to/setup-persistence-redis-cluster-in-kubertenes-7d5b7ffdbd98]

This stateful set was working fine with minikube , but when I am deploying it on kubernetes cluster(I have created with 2 machine) It is giving below error:

```
root@xen-727:/usr/local/bin# kubectl get pods
NAME              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
redis-cluster-0   0/1       Pending   0          13m

root@xen-727:/usr/local/bin# kubectl describe pod redis-cluster-0
Name:           redis-cluster-0
Namespace:      default
Node:           /
Labels:         app=redis-cluster
                controller-revision-hash=redis-cluster-b5b75cc79
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=redis-cluster-0
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  redis-cluster:
    Image:      tiroshanm/kubernetes-redis-cluster:latest
    Ports:      6379/TCP, 16379/TCP
    Command:
      /usr/local/bin/redis-server
    Args:
      /redis-conf/redis.conf
    Liveness:           exec [sh -c redis-cli -h $(hostname) ping] delay=20s timeout=1s period=3s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:          exec [sh -c redis-cli -h $(hostname) ping] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:        <none>
    Mounts:
      /data from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-h22jv (ro)
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  PodScheduled  False
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-redis-cluster-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-h22jv:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-h22jv
    Optional:   false
QoS Class:      BestEffort
Node-Selectors: <none>
Tolerations:    node.kubernetes.io/not-ready=:Exists:NoExecute for 300s
                node.kubernetes.io/unreachable=:Exists:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubObjectPath   Type            Reason                  Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------   --------        ------                  -------
  15m           14m             4       default-scheduler                       Warning         FailedScheduling        pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)


root@xen-727:/usr/local/bin# kubectl get pvc
NAME                   STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
data-redis-cluster-0   Pending                                      slow           15m

root@xen-727:/usr/local/bin# kubectl get pv
No resources found.
```

I created one storage class :

```
root@xen-727:/usr/local/bin# kubectl get sc
NAME             TYPE
slow (default)   kubernetes.io/gce-pd
```

But After search a lot , It seems that kubernetes is not using this storage class to create pv.

storage class code:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: slow
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
```

below is my complete code:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster
  labels:
    app: redis-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: redis-cluster
  replicas: 6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-cluster
      annotations:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis-cluster
        image: tiroshanm/kubernetes-redis-cluster:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: client
        - containerPort: 16379
          name: gossip
        command: ["/usr/local/bin/redis-server"]
        args: ["/redis-conf/redis.conf"]
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "redis-cli -h $(hostname) ping"
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "redis-cli -h $(hostname) ping"
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 3
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data
          readOnly: false
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        name: redis-cluster
      annotations:
        volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: anything
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
```

Expected output:
It should create 6 nodes, with 6 pvc and 6 pv.

Comment: Could you please share your PV and PVC yaml files?

Comment: PV and PVC will be created by stateful set automatically, we have defined PV Template :apiVersion: volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        name: redis-cluster
      annotations:
        volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: anything
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi

Comment: Yes, so please share the template? It is hard to guess what is written on those templates. Somehow PV and PVC's are not attached and hence the pods are not coming up

Comment: I have added the code in Question itself, now see the question please above.Thanks

Comment: PV doesn't get automatically created. PVC can be created using `volumeClaimTemplate` . You need to create PV before starting the pod so that the generated PVC can bound to those PV. I am adding PV template to the answer

Comment: Thanks prafull I will try this..but when I run the same statefulset in minikube then it automatically creates the pv and pvc.we are using concept of storage class.this problem is coming on kubernetes cluster.

Comment: If you remove the `annotations:` `volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: anything` from the `StatefulSet`, does it still cause issues in GKE?

Comment: Yes Michael , I also tried this...still same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a storage that you are requesting with `PersistentVolumeClaim`.

Example of Volume types are available [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/).

> A `PersistentVolume` (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator. It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster resource. PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a lifecycle independent of any individual pod that uses the PV. This API object captures the details of the implementation of the storage, be that NFS, iSCSI, or a cloud-provider-specific storage system.
>
> A `PersistentVolumeClaim` (PVC) is a request for storage by a user. It is similar to a pod. Pods consume node resources and PVCs consume PV resources. Pods can request specific levels of resources (CPU and Memory). Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., can be mounted once read/write or many times read-only).

If you are on [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/), you can use  [`gcePersistentDisk`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk)

> A `gcePersistentDisk` volume mounts a Google Compute Engine (GCE) [Persistent Disk](http://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks) into your Pod. Unlike `emptyDir`, which is erased when a Pod is removed, the contents of a PD are preserved and the volume is merely unmounted. This means that a PD can be pre-populated with data, and that data can be “handed off” between Pods.

You need to use the `gcloud` command to create a drive inside the [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/):

```
gcloud compute disks create --size=500GB --zone=us-central1-a my-data-disk
```

And using it inside a `POD`, like in the example below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    # This GCE PD must already exist.
    gcePersistentDisk:
      pdName: my-data-disk
      fsType: ext4
```

If you prefer, you can setup your own `nfs` server and use it inside Kubernetes, an example on how to set it up, is available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs).

You can also check the documentation on how to [use volumes on AWS](https://kubernetes-on-aws.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/using-volumes.html).

Hope this will be enough to help you.

Comment: I got the answer.

Comment: I have created one provisioner and pass it in my storage class...and give this storage class to persistence volume template...so automatically PVC and pv got created